# How can I change state in client-side in NEXT.js?

Tags: next.js, state-management

I have a simple tab component in NEXT. Here's my component code:

```
const Tabs = ({ tabItems }) => {

    const setActiveTab = (tabItem) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < tabItems.length; i++) {
            tabItems[i].active = false;
        }
        tabItem.active = true;
    }

    return <div>
        {
            tabItems.map(tabItem => <div
                className={tabItem.active ? "active-tab" : ""}
                onClick={() => setActiveTab(tabItem)}
            >{tabItem.title}</div>)
        }
    </div>
}
```

However, when I click on tab items, the state does not change.

How can I change state in client-side in NEXT?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change state from a parent like this. The way that you're doing, you're only changing the value of `tabItem` inside the children component.

You could use *Context API* to achieve the desired result, or just pass down a function from the parent, which would be the best if you're not passing props down too many components.

Code example:

`parent.tsx`:

```js
export const Parent = () => {
  const [tabItems, setTabItems] = useState()

  function changeTabItems(newValue) {
    setTabItems(newValue)
  }

  return <Child changeTabItems={changeTabItems} tabItems={tabItems}/>
}
```

`child.tsx`:

```js
export const Child = ({changeTabItems, tabItems}) => {
  function setActiveTab(tabItem) {
    let aux = tabItems
    for (var i = 0; i < tabItems.length; i++) {
      aux[i].active = false;
    }
    aux.active = true;
    changeTabItems({...aux})
  }

}
```